# image is spliting in tiles correctly only for 400*400 dimesion Image

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have implemented a puzzle based on jquery .But in my puzzle ,I am facing a problem when i am resizing image through paint(windows application)in 400*400 pixels and saving to my path file then my puzzle is spliting image pieces correctly but when i am loadin file which is high resolution,Pieces are not spliting correctly,please suggest me what i have to do ,so that i can split image correctly for all resolutions..please help me  ..

my image split code:

```
 var gridSize = 3(i.e 3rowsand 3columns)

   var percentage = 100 / (gridSize - 1);

 for (var i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++) {
                    var xpos = (percentage * (i % gridSize)) + '%';
                    console.log("xpos is", xpos);
                    console.log("ypos is ", ypos);
                    var ypos = (percentage * Math.floor(i / gridSize)) + '%';
                    var li = $('<li class="item" id="' + (i + 1) + '"data-value="' + (i) + '"></li>').css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + Puzzleimage + ')',
                        'background-size': (gridSize * 100) + '%',
                        'background-position': xpos + ' ' + ypos,
                        'border': '1px solid red',
                        'width': 220 / gridSize,
                        'height': 220 / gridSize
                    });
}
```

my imageSample which is not correct(look at pieces):-

[image]

Here is my plunker with 400*400 pixels which is correctly coming..

https://plnkr.co/edit/hL9s1I4LPnL8BvuKfbRM?p=preview

Comment: Why not create an example `plnkr` of the code that isn't working, rather than the one that is? Surely that would make far more sense...

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hL9s1I4LPnL8BvuKfbRM?p=preview..see the peices is not coming correctly ..because image is not in 400*400